# Validity of a function $g$ such that $g(x)=\{x\}$

Tags: set-theory

I've been reading some set theory lately, and I wanted to revisit a question I had in my first-year algebra course.  We had to prove that the set of Zermelo ordinals $\mathbb{S}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},...\}$ was a valid set under the ZFC axioms.  I originally did this by using the axiom schema of replacement and defining a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is exactly once $s\in\mathbb{S}$.  However, I wanted to try and re-do this using the recursion theorem as I believe this would be a cleaner approach.  The obvious way to do this is as follows:

Let $g(x)=\{x\}$, then by said theorem there is a unique sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $f_0=\emptyset$ and $f_{n+1}=g(f_n)$.  The only problem is, letting $\mathbb{U}$ be the class of all sets, we have that $g\subset\mathbb{U}\times\mathbb{U}$ so it is thus not known to be a set, invalidating it's being a function and thus the entire argument.  Is there an easy way to fix this or an alternative method to prove that $\mathbb{O}$ is a set using the recursion theorem.

The recursion theorem:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem

Comment: How do you get the set $S$ if the $f_n$'s are given?

Comment: The recursion theorem guarantees the existence of the function $\mathit{f}:/mathbb{N}\rightarrow/mathbb{S}$ such that we have, for every natural $n$,$(n,/mathit{f}_n)/in/mathit{f}$ so just take the projection map $(n,/mathit{f}_n)/rightarrow/mathit{f}_n$

Comment: In the version  of the recursion theorem I was taught (Hrbacek-Jech) a class function was OK as the basis. You just need to show that every $x$ has a unique successor set $g(x) = \{x\}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma this is the same book I’m currently reading. I’m assuming this stronger recursion theorem is the one they alluded to in chapter 4? In that case I’ll get there eventually because currently they’ve only done it with a function $g:\mathbb{A}\bigtimes\mathbb{N}\rightarrrow\mathbb{A}$ for a set $\mathbb{A}$

Comment: You can always view $g$ as a function HF to HF (where HF is the set of hereditary finite sets)... But then again the way to construct HF is by iterating the power set $\omega$ times (and the power set is a class function) which you could ask this same question about.

Comment: (Also I don't really see the difference between the two approaches. In the first approach, how do you construct the function $f$ if not by recursion? In the second how do you expect to draw the conclusion from the construction other than with replacement?)

Comment: But yes, the 'real answer' is that recursion was always meant to work with a $g$ as a class function.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the axiom of infinity we know that there exists an inductive set $X$. This is, $X$ satisfies the following property: $(\emptyset\in X)\wedge\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X)$.

Power set axiom guarantees that $A=\mathscr P(X)$ is a set. Now you can consider $g\subseteq X\times A$, and by induction theorem $\mathbb N\subseteq X$.

Comment: But not every element of $\mathbb{S}$ is in A.

Comment: You are completely right sir. My answer doesn't help. I will think if I can think of another way :/